# Android: Separate dynamically generated animated text views

Tags: java, android, animation

This is a loaded question. I'll try and provide only the relevant information.

I have *events* in the game I'm making. This event is basically triggered *every time* the user taps on the screen.

When an event is triggered, I have a "drop" of text displaying what the user just got. By "drop", I simply mean a `TextView` is displayed on-screen programatically, animated to translate upwards, and alpha-out at the end.

However, on a rare occasion, an event can contain more than just one item gained. Usually it's just coins, but sometimes it can be as many as 10 items. It's at this point, that all 10 items/coins textviews get stacked directly on top of each other making it impossible to read.

I feel as if all the code I have is irrelevant to post. My text drop code is simply `new TextView(getApplicationContext());` and setting animation etc. Nothing special.

I need a way to separate these text events so that when there are multiple events resulting from one tap, they are all legible. Any ideas?

Even more information: I've already tried creating a for loop of all my event items and using a handler to create a delay between all of the events, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: You may try this approach, instead of creating a Textview create a relative layout and add text views inside this realtive layout dynamically and assign some id and set "layout below" parameter for each textView and apply animation to Relative layout. You may also use **Linear Layout** instead of Relative layout.

Comment: @HarjotSinghOberai that's an interesting solution I hadn't thought of. I'll definitely implement this when I return to my PC tonight. I can already see this working as intended in my application. Thanks for the thought!